# Django Channel first steps error

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I'm following the Getting Started tutorial from Channels docs, but when I launch the runserver and try to load any page it gives me this error:

```
16:17:46 [django.request] ERROR Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\web\wr-kpi-dashboard\.venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 235, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request, response)
  File "C:\web\wr-kpi-dashboard\.venv\lib\site-packages\wr_security\middleware\log_access.py", line 39, in process_response
   'protocol': request.META['SERVER_PROTOCOL'],
KeyError: 'SERVER_PROTOCOL'
[2017/09/06 16:17:47] HTTP GET / 500 [0.63, 127.0.0.1:60297]
```

*settings.py*

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "asgiref.inmemory.ChannelLayer",
        "ROUTING": "dashboard.channels.routing.channel_routing",
    },
}
```

*routing.py*

```
from channels.routing import route
from consumers import ws_message
channel_routing = [
    route("websocket.receive", ws_message),
]
```

*consumers.py*

```
def ws_message(message):
    # ASGI WebSocket packet-received and send-packet message types
    # both have a "text" key for their textual data.
    message.reply_channel.send({
        "text": message.content['text'],
    })
```

Comment: This seems to be an error unrelated to `channels`. If you run django in plain mode without websockets (`manage.py runserver --noasgi`), do you still get the same error?

Comment: @hoefling you are right, i found out that this error wasn't related to django channels. Thx anyway!